# How to Access Views for Appointment entity in CRM 2013 using SQL?

Tags: sql-server, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I would like to see the list of views existing for an Appointment entity like "All Appointments", "My Appointments","Appointments Associated view".
I tried the following query but it is returning some 2454 records where Appointment has only 3 views.

```
   SELECT  s.Name
    FROM    dbo.SavedQuery s
            INNER JOIN dbo.EntityView LV ON LV.EntityId = EntityId
    WHERE   LV.Name = 'Appointment'
```

Please correct me where I am making mistake.

Comment: Don't query SavedQuery. What if someone changes the query? If you really need to query the db directly use the exact entity imo. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327905.aspx

Comment: But I dont find how to fetch the views tied to the entity. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the list of public views for any entity from onpremise CRM database, use the query like below:

```
SELECT Name
FROM SavedQuery
WHERE ReturnedTypeCode = '<entity logical name>'
```

For Appointment, it should be `WHERE ReturnedTypeCode = 'appointment'`

Update:

I don't have access to on-premise to query the SQL, but [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328457.aspx#Anchor_2) says like below:

> SavedQuery.ReturnedTypeCode: Matches the logical name of the entity.

Try 4201 for appointment & see if it results.

Comment: ReturnedTypeCode is integer value.